Why does synchronous code execute insert mysql faster than asynchronous code
At present, I refactor the code in the project, because the code involves more database operations, so consider using asyncio, currently all database operations are implemented using asynchronous, and then test the original code (original code is synchronous) and asynchronous code, found that synchronous code is faster, why?
About the difference between synchronous code and asynchronous code:

operating database: synchronous code uses pymysql, asynchronous code uses aiomysql, asyncio;
pandas was used for data calculation;
The code logic is the same;
The same computer;
The same wifi;
python version: synchronous code is 3.6, asynchronous code is 3.8;
Django version: synchronous code is 3.2.25, asynchronous code is 4.2.11;
Asynchronous code uses asynchronous views that Django supports, such as:

    @method_decorator(csrf_exempt, name='dispatch')
    class AsyncExampleView(View):
        async def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):


aiomysql version: 0.2.0, pymysql version: 1.1.0

Here is my code to create the database connection pool and execute the SQL:
import aiomysql
import asyncio
import logging
from django.conf import settings

log = logging.getLogger("logs")


class DatabasePool:
    _instance = None

    def __init__(self, db_configs):
        self._loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        self._db_configs = db_configs
        self._pools = {}
        self._locks = {}

    @classmethod
    async def get_instance(cls, db_configs=None):
        if cls._instance is None:
            cls._instance = cls(db_configs or settings.DATABASES)
            await cls._instance._initialize_pools()
        return cls._instance

    async def _initialize_pools(self):
        for name, config in self._db_configs.items():
            if name == "default":
                continue
            try:
                log.info(f"Creating pool for database: {name}")
                self._pools[name] = await aiomysql.create_pool(
                    host=config["HOST"],
                    port=config["PORT"],
                    user=config["USER"],
                    password=config["PASSWORD"],
                    db=config["DB"],
                    charset=config['OPTIONS']['charset'],
                    autocommit=True,
                    maxsize=20,
                    minsize=2,
                    cursorclass=aiomysql.DictCursor
                )
                self._locks[name] = asyncio.Lock()  # 为每个数据库创建一个锁
            except Exception as e:
                log.error(f"Failed to create pool for {name}: {e}", exc_info=True)
                raise


    async def execute_sql(self, db_name, sql, args=None, executemany=False):
        if db_name not in self._locks:
            raise ValueError(f"No lock found for database: {db_name}")
        lock = self._locks[db_name]
        async with lock:
            pool = self._pools.get(db_name)
            if not pool:
                raise ValueError(f"No pool found for database: {db_name}")
            async with pool.acquire() as conn:
                async with conn.cursor() as cur:
                    try:
                        if executemany:
                            await cur.executemany(sql, args or ())
                        else:
                            await cur.execute(sql, args or ())

                        if sql.strip().upper().startswith("SELECT"):
                            result = await cur.fetchall()
                        else:
                            result = cur.rowcount
                    except Exception as e:
                        # Log the exception or handle it as needed
                        raise
                    return result

async def exec_sql_async(db_name, sql, args=None, executemany=False):
    db_pool = await DatabasePool.get_instance()
    return await db_pool.execute_sql(db_name, sql, args, executemany)

SQL:
insert_fen = INSERT INTO example (id, name, age, ...) VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)

Call:
list_fen_final = [[0, 0, 29, '4', 9, 'japan', 2, 0, 1, 1, 'one', Decimal('21.00'), 19, 18, 'fnyzzb', 1, 0, 0.0],....] total count: 894
await exec_sql_async("example_database", insert_fen, list_fen_final, executemany=True)

I want to know why asynchronous is slower than synchronous, and is there a good solution?

Try submit a minimal dummy code to illustrate the issue.

@DG I modified the article slightly because I found the execution slow, mainly because of insert statements, but I don't know why? Shouldn't asynchronous IO operations be faster than synchronous IO operations? Now the opposite is true
